# How to embed report in webpage for viewing on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, powerbi

I have a report embedded on a website. Is there a way in the html to configure the report to change dimensions if a user is viewing the page on a mobile device?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using power bi mobile for that ?

If yes you have to rotate mobile in to landscape view to get full dashboard experience, Otherwise you get limited data.